# JQuery slideDown & slideUp en menu

Tags: jquery

Tengo la siguiente página en la cual tengo problemas con el menú mobile:

http://www.endeavor.cl/

Al cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla a resolución de teléfono, tienes un menú con varios items que tienen su propio sub-menu. Cuando haces click en estos items, aparece el sub-menu oculto con un efecto slide-down, y cuando le vuelves a hacer click o haces click en otro item, el sub-menu se vuelve a ocultar con slide-up. E problema ocurre que cuando vuelves a hacer "resize" de la pantalla o haces scroll o algo, el efecto se sale de control. Ahora pasa que cuando le haces click una vez, se ejecuta automáticamente el slide-down y el slide-up después, es decir, los sub-menús se des-ocultan e inmediatamente se ocultan solos. ¿Qué está mal?

Este es el código:

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function () {   
    if ($(window).width() >= 1000){ 
      $("#menu-top").removeClass();
      $("#menu-top").addClass("desktop");
    }else{
      $("#menu-top").removeClass();
      $("#menu-top").addClass("touch");
      $("#menu-top.touch .menu-item-has-children a").addClass("primer-boton").css('cursor','pointer');
      $("#menu-top.touch .sub-menu a").removeClass();
      $("#menu-top.touch .primer-boton").removeAttr("href");
      $('#menu-top.touch .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').parent().click(function() {
        var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
        if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
        $(submenu).slideDown(200);
        } else {
        $(submenu).slideUp(200);
        }
      });
      
    }

  });
```

Comment: si revisas tu consola aparece este error. TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function. line 341:5

Comment: Yo creo que el submenu al cambiar de tamaño, adquiere otras dimensiones que las que se ven, entonces al dar click se descompone. Si fuera lo que comenta Rene Limon, dejaría de funcionar todo.